# Vue prop from optional router param is empty string instead of default value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm trying to pass an optional parameter clientId to my component from the route:

```
//router.js
{
   path: "/new-services-request/:clientId?",
   name: "NewServicesRequest",
   component: () => import("../views/ServicesRequest/NewServicesRequest.vue"),
   props: true
},
```

In my component I have:

```
//NewServicesRequest.vue
const props = defineProps({
  clientId: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: "0"
  }
});
```

Now, in my layout when I click the link `to="/new-services-request"` the page loads but the `props.clientId` is empty string `""` rather than `"0"`.
Any help?

Comment: What is empty? undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to explicitely pass `undefined` or `null` param in this case.

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'NewServicesRequest', params: { clientId: id } }">
```

```js
const id = ref(undefined)  // able to programmatically set to whatever value
```

Comment: If I pass parameter, I'll pass directly the "0" as default, the problem is I dont want to pass any parameter and the component should set clientId=0 by default. Only should be updated if I pass the parameter explicit in the route "/new-services-request/73 for example.

Comment: vue-router sees `/new-services-request` as having an implicit empty string following it.  it's not smart enough to understand.  you have to explicitly pass a value or undefined if the prop you're working with is specifically a string.  I've updated the answer if you want a more programmatic approach

Comment: The real problem is that this a new feature in my existing component and I need to update multiples route call to this component in all my webapp even in an external website witch I don't manage. I know you can set a optional parameter in the route, that way is not mandatory, the problem is in the component doesn't set the default value I want if not pass any parameter. I already solve it creating a new var and use it as real id: const id = ref(props.clientId == "" ? 0 : props.clientId);